# How to handle ExpiredAuthorizationException (The authorization has expired) in spring-social-facebook

Tags: java, facebook, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I'm using `spring-social-facebook` and sometimes, after some time the authentication seems to expire and I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.social.ExpiredAuthorizationException: The authorization has expired.
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleFacebookError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:83)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.FacebookErrorHandler.handleError(FacebookErrorHandler.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:667)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:620)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:595)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForObject(RestTemplate.java:303)
    at org.springframework.social.facebook.api.impl.SocialContextTemplate.getSocialContext(SocialContextTemplate.java:120)
```

I don't know how to handle with this error...Would it be possible to automatically reconnect after the authentication expires?

Versions used:

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

I've found similar questions in SO:

- [How to handle ExpiredAuthorizationException happening in spring social facebook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21188573/how-to-handle-expiredauthorizationexception-happening-in-spring-social-facebook)
  I think this solution doesn't work with my newer versions.
- [How to recover from a Spring Social ExpiredAuthorizationException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16358067/how-to-recover-from-a-spring-social-expiredauthorizationexception):This solution only works for the spring-social-google particular case.

Any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this issue you must add a `ReconnectFilter` to the social configuration Java file:

```
    @Bean
    public ReconnectFilter apiExceptionHandler(UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, UserIdSource userIdSource) {
        return new ReconnectFilter(usersConnectionRepository, userIdSource);
    }
```

This `ReconnectFilter` depends on an UserIdSource Bean to retrieve the user information and refresh the connection. You must override it:

```
 @Override
    @Bean
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new UserIdSource() {
            @Override
            public String getUserId() {
                User user = getUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in");
                }
                return user.getId();
            }
        };
    }
```

You can see the entire Social Config file below:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EnableSocial
public class SocialConfig  extends SocialConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addConnectionFactories(ConnectionFactoryConfigurer cfConfig, Environment env) {
        cfConfig.addConnectionFactory(new FacebookConnectionFactory(env.getProperty("facebook.appKey"), env.getProperty("facebook.appSecret")));
    }


    @Bean
    public UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {
        return new UserConnectionRepositoryImpl(connectionFactoryLocator);
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public UserIdSource getUserIdSource() {
        return new UserIdSource() {
            @Override
            public String getUserId() {
                User user = getUser();
                if (user == null) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in");
                }
                return user.getId();
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ReconnectFilter apiExceptionHandler(UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository, UserIdSource userIdSource) {
        return new ReconnectFilter(usersConnectionRepository, userIdSource);
    }


    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public ConnectionRepository connectionRepository(ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator) {

        User user = getUser();
        if (user == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to get a ConnectionRepository: no user signed in");
        }
        return usersConnectionRepository(connectionFactoryLocator).createConnectionRepository(user.getId());
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "request", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public Facebook facebook(ConnectionRepository repository) {
        Connection<Facebook> connection = null;

        if (repository != null) {
           connection = repository.findPrimaryConnection(Facebook.class);
        }

        return connection != null ? connection.getApi() : null;
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Xavi Torrens